# How to get estimated download time

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I am creating a web browser in C# winforms, and for the download form, I need to get the estimated download time. I'm using the System.Net.WebClient class for downloading. Here's the code so far:

```
private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
   {
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        double recieve = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double total = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = recieve / total * 100;
        label7.Text = percentage.ToString() + "% complete";
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    }));
}
```

[image: DownloadForm.Designer]

Comment: You can't without downloading some data.  A URL has multiple hops.  The rate is going to be the slowest hop in the connection.  So some hops may be 10M others 100M, and others on Fiber Optics.

Comment: An estimate can be calculated in many ways and it's not quite clear which approach you're looking for. For example you could say `timeTakenSoFar / percentReceived` or some calculation of the download speed the last second multiplied by how much data is still missing. Is an estimate even useful though given how much it can fluctuate?

Comment: Why are you invoking there? The event is raised on the same Thread, so now you call Invoke() on the UI Thread. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only estimate the time once you have already downloaded a part of it. Start a `StopWatch` when starting the download

```cs
private readonly StopWatch _stopWatch = new();
private long _totalBytesReceived;
```

Starting the download

```cs
_stopWatch.Restart();
_totalBytesReceived = 0;
StartDownloading();
```

In `Client_DownloadProgressChanged`:

```cs
long received = e.BytesReceived;
_totalBytesReceived += received;
long totalEstimatedMilliseconds =
    _stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * e.TotalBytesToReceive / _totalBytesReceived;
```

All these numbers are given as `long`. It makes no sense to convert them to `string` just to parse them to `double` and later to truncate the `double` and to convert to string again for display. Just keep the `long` during the whole process. `long` is always a whole number and does not require truncation.

---

You get the percentage for free, since the [DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.downloadprogresschangedeventargs?view=net-5.0) has [ProgressPercentage Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.progresspercentage?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_ProgressChangedEventArgs_ProgressPercentage). Intellisense reveals it. (You still have to calculate the estimated time so).